# Save List <Uri> inside the object

Tags: android, kotlin

**This is object class**

```
data class SavedInfo(

val uris: ArrayList<Uri>,

) : Serializable
```

**onSaveInstanceState method**

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        val savedInfo = SavedInfo(uris)
        outState.putSerializable("uris", savedInfo)
    }
```

**Get instance**

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            val savedInfo = savedInstanceState.getSerializable("uris") as SavedInfo
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.